# Loop terminal command for combining PNG to GIF animation

Tags: 12.04, command-line, imagemagick

I am trying to combine some PNG images to make a GIF animation. To do this I have installed ImageMagic and am trying to execute the command:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 inputfiles*.png animaion.gif
```

I have a lot of image files that I am trying to combine so I don't really want to type them all out individually, is there anyway I can execute this command as some sort of loop, or alternatively a better method of creating an animation from these images?

I have written a program to output all the file names so I can just copy and paste them into the terminal, this works but if anyone knows a better way to do this it would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I have written a program to output all the file names so i can just copy and paste them into the terminal, this works but if anyone knows a better way to do this it would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please do not add comments to specify things --- you can just edit your question whenever you need.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, if you have `mypgrogram` that outputs the list of filenames, you should be able to simply do

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 $(myprogram) animation.gif
```

The `$(...)` operator is a bash shell operation that runs the indicated command and then replaces itself with the output (more or less... [the shell is a quite powerful tool](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)).